# How to apply validation on any single field having same name Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have a project that consists of multilingual functionality. So I'm creating a form that consists of multiple languages to be inserted if User wants.
But validation should be like if any of the fields having the same name consist value then leave rest one like as

**Form**

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="name[EN]" />
   <input type="text" name="name[AR]" />
   <input type="text" name="name[FR]" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Now I want to validate that if any one of these fields have value then submit form else throw a validation

So I've tried Laravels **required_if**, but it didn't work.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name.*'        => 'required_if:name,1',
    ];
}
```

So how to make such validation in laravel

Comment: can you share how you tried `required_if` ?

Comment: @apokryfos I've updated my question

Comment: doing `"name" => "required"` should work in that it will need a non-empty array I think

Comment: @apokryfos its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've searched but could not find a built in way of doing this. You can create your own rule using

```
php artisan make:rule NonEmptyFiltered
```

and then define the rule as:

```
class NotEmptyFiltered implements Rule {
    public function passes($attribute, $value) {
        return !empty(array_filter($value));
    }

    public function message() {
        return ':attribute must have at least one non-null element';
    }
}
```

You can then do:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => [ new NonEmptyFiltered() ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: This actually works +1. Thanks. I don't have any idea about this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should do the trick:

```
$rules = [
    'name.EN' => 'required_without_all:name.AR,name.FR',
    'name.AR' => 'required_without_all:name.EN,name.FR',
    'name.FR' => 'required_without_all:name.EN,name.AR',
];
```

The rule makes the field to be required if the other fields are empty https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-required-without-all.

Comment: This one works but the case over here is that input are created dynamically. If user enter another language then it should be handled dynamically.

Comment: @devmyb, can you make your rules dynamic as well?

Comment: that's what I'm looking for

Comment: @devmyb, I mean if your languages are store in the database or something you can get them when validating and make the rules for them. Otherwise you have to make your own custom validation rule.

Comment: Yes they are stored in database only. But have no idea to append those within my validation